# Unity3D Only single if statement being called

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm having issue with my code.
Only the first if statement is being called.
I know my level is increasing, however after the first statement is called and the level increases the continue button is still shown even if the score is lower than called for.

```
private void PlayBuzzer()
{
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(buzzer);
    timeRemaining -= 1;
    endPanel.SetActive(true);
    if (PlayerScore.score >= 15 && level == 1) // THIS ONE WORKS
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
// EVERYTHING BELOW HERE DOES NOT - Score Below 35 still shows 'Continue'
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 35 && level == 2)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 45 && level == 3)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 70 && level == 4)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 120 && level == 5)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 160 && level == 6)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 230 && level == 7)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (PlayerScore.score >= 300 && level == 8)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(true);
        GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(false);
    }
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things:
1. Is the first if called if score is say 40 and level is more than 1?
2. Also, did you put a breakpoint and what the value of the 'level' variable actually is when I goes to the first case when i should have gone to the second?

Comment: Please debug your own code before posting. All the `if`/`else` statements are doing the-same thing so you won't really know which one is working or not. Put `Debug.Log` in every `if` statement then tell us what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok without knowing where PlayBuzzer() is called and if level is increased before or after that, finding the problem is really hard. Did you debug the program?

anyway I took the freedom to shorten your function, in order to follow the DRY principle:

```
private void PlayBuzzer()
{
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(buzzer);
    timeRemaining -= 1;
    endPanel.SetActive(true);
    var scores = new List<int> { 15, 35, 45, 70, 120, 160 };
    var mustRestart = PlayerScore.score < scores[level - 1];
    GameObject.Find("Restart").SetActive(mustRestart);
    GameObject.Find("Continue").SetActive(!mustRestart);
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}
```

you must of cause insure that your level is between 1 and scores.Count.